# Generating new keystore with same app and package name, because I lost my old one

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I lost my keystore and as I've seen in other questions here, it is impossible for me to upgrade my app. 
So I've decided to generate a new keystore and and sign my apk. However, I want the app name and package to remain the same. I will just delete the old app and upload the new one.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the app on your own device, or devices you control, you can remove them, then replace with the same package name / new signature (sometimes a reboot is needed after uninstall / before re-install).

If you're talking about the Android market, no, you cannot delete it or replace it with a new signature; you'll need to change the package name.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've submitted an application to the Android Market all future submissions must be signed using the same Keystore.  You should always back this up. [From the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html):

> Also, the package name must be the same as the existing version and
>   the .apk file must be signed with the same private key. If the package
>   name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing
>   version, Google Play will consider it a new application, publish it as
>   such, and will not offer it to existing users as an update.